# How to open file browser dialog in a dynamically created form?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, user-interface, sta

I have two forms in my application, one is generated at the design time and the other one is dynamically generated at the run time. The form generated at the run time has a context menu in it which has a item which opens the `FolderBrowserDialog`. Whenever, I try to click on that item error occurs saying that

```
  Current thread must be set to single thread apartment (STA) mode before OLE  

  calls can be made. Ensure that your Main function has STAThreadAttribute  

  marked on it. This exception is only raised if a debugger is attached to the  

  process.
```

Th solution to the above problem as explained on other questions is to mark the `Main()` method as `[STA Thread]` but that is already there in my case. So, How can I correct this problem?
The way I am calling my dialog is:-

```
    private void RightClickMenuClicked(object sender, ToolStripItemClickedEventArgs e)
    {
       if (e.ClickedItem.ToString() == "Copy")
        {
           FolderBrowsing.ShowDialog() ; 
           // Do other stuff here ....
        }
   }
```

Comment: Can you post some code on how you do that?

Comment: @Szymon I have posted some of the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know how you are calling `ShowDialog` Method . You can try the code below

```
    private DialogResult STAShowDialog(FolderBrowserDialog dialog)
    {
        DialogState state = new DialogState();
        state.dialog = dialog;
        System.Threading.Thread t = new  
               System.Threading.Thread(state.ThreadProcShowDialog);
        t.SetApartmentState(System.Threading.ApartmentState.STA);
        t.Start();
        t.Join();
        return state.result;
    }

    public class DialogState
    {
      public DialogResult result;
      public FolderBrowserDialog dialog;


      public void ThreadProcShowDialog()
      {
        result = dialog.ShowDialog();
      }
    }
```

and in your Button click or somewhere you can try

```
     private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FolderBrowserDialog _myfolderDialog= new FolderBrowserDialog();
        frm.InitializeLifetimeService();


        DialogResult _result= STAShowDialog(_myfolderDialog);
        if (result== DialogResult.OK)
        {
            //Do your stuff
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

In Windows Forms or WPF, user interface can run only in the **single thread**. You have to enclose your additional window calling into [Dispatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) by using `Invoke` method - this will force the UI thread to deal with it. (Kyle's approach is a bit similar)